# Why the screen will flash when a Dialog disappeared?

Tags: android, dialog

I added a dark shadow of the screen when a Dialog is shown,here is the code ,but when the dialog is dismissed,the screen will flash. Please tell me how to deal with it?

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
 lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
 getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Check if your activity is restarted or any call in activity's onResume()

Comment: @mzeus.bolt Thanks.The activity works well,and I found this article:http://www.jianshu.com/p/7ec7d2ff450d